# linq to nhibernate compareto not supported

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, nhibernate

I've got linq to nhibernate query:

```
var listka = 
    from i in FakturyZakupu.Queryable 
    where String.Compare(i.REJESTRY.REJ_KOD,sbWartoscBetween1.ToString()) >= 0 
    && String.Compare(i.REJESTRY.REJ_KOD,sbWartoscBetween2.ToString()) <= 0 
    select i;

lista = listka.ToList();
```

And it is compiling very well, but if I use it, the exception is thrown:

> NotSupportedException int32 CompareTo(System.String, System.String)

How could I take using linq query string values between two values. Like in SQL:
select * from table where id between a and b ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate's Linq provider is very [extendable](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/06/14/linq-to-nhibernate-extensions.aspx). You could extend it to allow any expression, as long as you can write that expression in HQL, since NHibernate's Linq is converting to HQL.

So, if you write the extension for Between, your code could look like this:

```
var listka = 
    from i in FakturyZakupu.Queryable 
    where i.REJESTRY.REJ_KOD.Between(sbWartoscBetween1, sbWartoscBetween2) 
    select i;

lista = listka.ToList();
```

Here are some links to get you started:

- [NHibernate Linq provider extension by Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.ba/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)
- [Linq to NHibernate: String.Equals with StringComparison option](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/linq-to-nhibernate-string.equals-with-stringcomparison-option)
- [NHibernate 3 - Extending the Linq Provider to fix some   System.NotSupportedException](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception)
- [NHibernate - Customize the Linq provider to call your user defined SQL functions](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-customize-linq-provider-user-defined-sql-functions)
- [Linq to NHibernate extensions](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/06/14/linq-to-nhibernate-extensions.aspx)
- [Creating In and NotIn extension methods for NHibernate 3 Linq Provider](http://gedgei.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-in-and-notin-extension-methods-for-nhibernate-3-linq-provider/)
- [Extend NHibernate-LINQ for Regex-Matching](http://sentinel101.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/extend-nhibernate-linq-for-regex-matching/)
- [Custom LINQ Extensions for NHibernate](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/custom-linq-extensions-for-nhibernate)

Comment: Your first and fifth links are the same. Maybe you were willing to link to http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.fr/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html for your first. And you may want to add http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/custom-linq-extensions-for-nhibernate to your list, it is the lightest way to add some SQL function support.

Comment: @Frédéric thanks. You're right. Fixed the link and added new "Custom LINQ Extensions for NHibernate" link.

Answer (score 0):

In NHibernate v3.3.3, String.Compare is supported. A `String.Compare(MyProp, "value") > 0` in a `Where` expression would produce sql similar to `where MyProp > 'value'`.

Answer (score -1):

With queries like that, you can avoid the compare to by simply using the greater than (>) or less than (<) operators instead of String.Compare.  For example:

```
var listka =
    from i in FakturyZakupu.Queryable
    where i.REJESTRY.REJ_KOD > sbWartoscBetween1.ToString() &&
    i.REJESTRY.REJ_KOD < sbWartoscBetween2.ToString()
    select i;
```

Your success with may depend upon your database's interpretation of string comparisons, but should generally work just fine.

Comment: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'