# NHibernate Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlParameter' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to query my address location to find out addresses which are within the specific radius. Below is my where clause and `results` is an `IEnumerable<Properties>`

```
 Func<Address, bool> predicate = l =>
 {
    if (l.Location == null && l.Longitude.HasValue && l.Latitude.HasValue)
    {
       var point = new Point(l.Longitude.Value, l.Latitude.Value);
       return point.Distance(p) <= 300;
    }
    return false;
  };

  results = results.Where(x => predicate(x.Address));
```

However, I'm getting an exception from NHibernate as

> "Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlParameter' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'.

How can I fix this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that NHibernate can't execute your predicate in your db via sql. Try to use some simple types that NHibernate can translate into sql.

Comment: Simple types in the sense? You mean using `Point` type here?

Comment: Something that your db understands. What are the types of `Longitude` and `Latitude`? Is it possible to make the `point.Distance(p)` calculation by yourself? I don't know how the `Distance()` method works but maybe you can do something like `l.Longitude => 300 && l.Longitude <= 300`.

Comment: `latitude` & `longitude`are just a double. I've no problem with `point.Distance(p)` as I've an another query which works perfectly for the `point.Distance(p)`.

Comment: but `point.Distance(p)` can't be executed in the db. Are you sure that you don't execute this in an already fetched collection in your memory? Please take a look in the sql that NHibernate generates for your working method, you will see that NHibernate didn't executes `point.Distance(p)` in your db. Btw. what is `results`? Is this a `query` or a `List`? If it should be a List, call `.ToList()` before `.Where()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LINQ expressions, not lambdas!
Try this instead:

```
Expression<Func<Address, bool>> predicate = ...
```

Comment: Not enough... Its lambda is a multi-line lambda, using a block of code. I am not aware of any linq provider that could handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Your filtering expression cannot be translated to SQL. It is a multi-line expression. [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate), as any other orm LINQ provider, requires simple one liner lambda that can be translated to SQL.

Furthermore, your filtering expression use a class performing some computation (`Distance()` in your case). The LINQ provider will have no knowledge of how to convert that to SQL, unless you [extend it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469134/1178314). Better rewrite your computing in the lambda, if it can be written in a SQL translatable way.

If you need your predicate in many places, you may write a function to get it in a local var before using it.

```
private Expression<Func<Address, bool>> GetFilterByMaxDistance(double maxDistance)
{
    // replace ??? with your computation, without block of code (no `{}`) nor call to 
    // functions not known for being handled by the LINQ provider
    return a => ??? <= maxDistance;
}

...

    var predicate = GetFilterByMaxDistance(300);
    results = results.Where(predicate);
```

**Otherwise**, if your `results` local variable is already 'sufficiently filtered' for having reasonable performances, call `.AsEnumerable()` before applying your filter, this time only as a `Func<Address, bool>`, not as an `Expression<Func<Address, bool>>`.

Calling `.AsENumerable()` before applying `.Where(predicate)` will cause your predicate to get executed in memory by .Net runtime, without the need to convert it to SQL.
But of course this will cause the filtering to occur in your app rather than in the DB.